# SSH Reverse Tunnel: Bind Address is ignored

Tags: ip, configuration, ssh-tunnel, ifconfig

I'm trying to configure a server in one site to act as a proxy for several servers in another site using SSH. The server has one physical interface in its local network:

```
eth0 10.1.1.10
```

This server has multiple virtual interfaces created like so:

```
server$ ifconfig eth0:0 10.1.1.200 netmask 255.255.255.128 broadcast 10.1.1.255
```

I have verified that in the local network this virtual interface is distinct from the actual interface by binding listeners to both. This is facilitated by enabling ip forwarding in `/etc/sysctl.d/01-ip_forwarding.conf` : `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

As an example, this works, producing two different files:

```
client$ curl 10.1.1.10 > 10.txt
client$ curl 10.1.1.200 > 200.txt
```

I have enabled gateway ports in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` : `GatewayPorts yes`

From the remote server I run this:

```
remote$ ssh -N -R 10.1.1.200:443:remote:443 user@server
```

Then I check the listening port using netstat:

```
server$ nestat -tln
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:443            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::443                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

(I have removed irrelevant lines)

I want it to bind to 10.1.1.200:443, but instead it binds to 0.0.0.0:443.

Why won't it bind to the correct ip?

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `GatewayPorts` to `clientspecified` on the server (in the `sshd_config` file) in order to be able to bind remote tunnels to any interface. According to the [man page of sshd_config(5)](https://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config):

> `GatewayPorts` can be used to specify that sshd should allow remote port forwardings to bind to non-loopback addresses, thus allowing other hosts to connect.  The argument may be `no` to force remote port forwardings to be available to the local host only, `yes` to force remote port forwardings to bind to the wildcard address, or `clientspecified` to allow the client to select the address to which the forwarding is bound.  The default is `no`.